# Rails 3.1: Why do both variables get updated when I only update one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Sorry if that title doesn't make sense, I'm new to Rails and I'm building a poker game to learn the framework.  I have a Game model...

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :players, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :community_cards, :class_name => "Card", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :used_cards, :class_name => "Card", :dependent => :destroy
```

...with a few associations for players, community_cards, and used_cards.  However, when I add card objects to used_cards...

```
new_card = Card.create(:suit => random_suit, :face => random_face)
used_cards << new_card
```

...then community_cards get updated with the same cards so both used_cards and community_cards have the same objects in them.  What gives?

Thanks so much in advance for all your wisdom!

Comment: place your ` update action`  code from controller too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Card model stores a single game_id field, and that new card is then set as a child to the game object, both arrays get updated. There is no way for Rails to know what's what. However, there is a solution.

If you look at the has_many documentation on api.rubyonrails.org, you will see there is a conditions option. So what I suggest you do is add a boolean field to the card model. Then add a condition to each of your has_many declarations for the Card model to check against the boolean value. For example

```
rails g migration add_used_to_cards used:boolean
```

Then edit the migration file generated, so you can set a default. The add_column method should then look like this:

```
 add_column :cards, :used, :boolean, :default => false
```

Then change your has_many like so:

```
has_many :community_cards, :class_name => "Card", :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => { :used => false }
has_many :used_cards, :class_name => "Card", :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => { :used => true }
```

That should do the trick.